# How can Windows 10 boot directly to laptop?

Tags: windows-10, boot

Please see the combined screenshot beneath, from my grandpa's new Lenovo laptop. After clicking the power button, his old and my grandma's Windows laptops boot directly to the desktop without any interceding screens like in Screenshot 1 requiring user feedback.

[image]

[Screenshot 2 is detailed here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3539-sign-user-account-automatically-windows-10-startup.html#option1), and [4 here](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/change-password-windows-10).

Comment: So you're saying that the moment they press the power button, to turn the laptop on, it boots and then automatically logs them in and takes them to their desktop to begin using, and you're wondering why does it not show them the "sign in" button?

Comment: The fact your "Screenshot 2" in your combined picture has "Require users to enter a username and password to sign in to this computer" is unticked will have prompted for a username and password of an account to automatically sign-in to - hence the computer, upon booting, automatically signs in to the provided account, thus, essentially, bypassing the login screen (well, it doesn't, it just has the ifnormation to do the login for you).

Comment: It's possible that the lack of a user password has broken the process at this point, and stopped it from working. I suggest setting a password for the user and then going through the process again... or following the steps in my answer below.

Comment: @Kinnectus No. "the moment they press the power button, to turn the laptop on, it boots and then automatically logs them in and takes them to their desktop to begin using": this is the goal. They're trying to shun the "sign-in" button.

Comment: @Stese What does this mean please: "broken the process at this point"?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal : by that I mean that if the user doesn't have a password, it may disallow the automatic login. Hence, not having a password breaks the process. (it's similar to the issue where you can't log in to an Windows shared folder, if the user used as the login name does not have a password set)

Answer (score 0):

**NB
Modifying the registry incorrectly can cause damage to the operating system on the computer. Ensure you take a backup first, and that you feel comfortable making changes which could render the computer needing expert assistance. YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED.**

Using the following as a guide :-

[Guide link - Method 3](https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/how-to-set-auto-login-in-windows-10/)

**Before you start, create a password for the user you wish to logon automatically.**

1. Press windows-key + R and type 'regedit'
2. Click 'Yes' on the 'User Account Control' Prompt
3. Navigate through the registry to 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE→SOFTWARE→Microsoft→WindowsNT→CurrentVersion→Winlogon'
4. Find the AutoAdminLogon key, right click, and choose 'Modify'
5. Change the value to '1'.
6. Find the DefaultUserName key and right click and choose 'Modify'.
7. change the value to the Username of the user to automatically sign in.
8. Right click on an empty space in the 'key display' of reg edit, and create a new string value called 'DefaultPassword'. Capitalisation is important here.
9. Modify the key value to the password of the user.
10. Make sure the changes are shown in the window, and reboot the PC. It should automatically go direct to the desktop.

Comment: @Greek - Area 51 Proposal : did this work?

Comment: +1. Thanks: it did! But startup time feels slower now. I hope you don't mind, but I may post a bounty to this question before I accept.